# Can a TValueListEdit have some item ReadOnly and others don't?

Tags: c++builder-10.4-sydney

I am using a `TValueListEditor` in C++Builder 10.4 Community Edition.

I would like to have some items be read-only and other items be editable. I think that the `goEditing` setting is making all of them editable, although I am setting some of the items as `ReadOnly=true`. I would like a comment on that.

Another question: on the same control, for items which are of types `esPickList` or `esEllipsis`, I need to click twice on them to show the buttons at the end of the value to make a choice, while the Object Inspector on the IDE shows them right on selecting them. Is there any configuration that should be made to change this behaviour?

Comment: Regarding the 1st issue, `goEditing` should have no effect on `ReadOnly`, so please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] showing how you are adding items to the `TValueListEditor` and configuring them.

Comment: Regarding the 2nd issue, the Object Inspector is a custom UI, it does not use a `TValueListEditor` at all.

Comment: Never mind, I have realized that the ReadOnly property of TItemProp object is intended to obly the user to only choose options instead of typing, so I have found that, if I want the item to be a non editable nor changeable, I must use it as esSimple and ReadOnly, and that the TValueListEditor is not the suitable component I should use in my application.